# Is it possible to capture the output of the FM radio?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8

The [FM Radio Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.radio.fmradio%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) seems to only enable the control of the radio.  There is the ability to [capture input from the microphone](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Microphone-Sample-b2ebe8b6), but I was looking for something similar to capture the output of the FM radio because I'd like to record live radio as is [possible with video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207006%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (using the [capturesource class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.capturesource%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).